# Why is the size and values of this OpenCV Matrix incorrect?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I use the following function to return a weight matrix of values between 0 and 1 depending on how close to the center a particular matrix position is. Also after a threshold the values are all 1 (it is like plateau with the points closer to center having value 1 and points away from center after a threshold of distance linearly fall from 1 to 0 at the edges)?

```
cv::Mat2f getWeightsMatrix(int N, int M, float r){
    cv::Mat2f weights = cv::Mat2f(N,M);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<M;j++){
            if(i<=floor(N*(1-r)/2)){
                if(j<=floor(M*(1-r)/2)){
                    weights[i][j]=((float)(i/N-j/M)/(1-r));
                }
                else{
                    weights[i][j]=(2*(float)(i/N)/(1-r));
                }
            }
            else if (i>=floor(N*(1+r)/2)){
                if(j>=floor(M*(1+r)/2)){
                    weights[i][j]=(((float)((N-i)/N))-((float)((M-j)/M)))/(1-r);
                }
                else{
                    weights[i][j]=(2*(float)((N-i)/N)/(1-r));
                }
            }
            else{
                if(j<=floor(M*(1-r)/2)){
                    weights[i][j]=(2*(float)(j/M)/(1-r));
                }
                else if(j>=floor(M*(1+r)/2)){
                    weights[i][j]=(2*(float)((M-j)/M)/(1-r));
                }
                else{
                    weights[i][j]=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << weights << endl;
    return weights;
}
```

Now my problem is that I am having some casting issues and only values 0 and 1 are being returned (no floats). Also my matrix size displayed by the cout is 20x10 when I call the function with N=10, M=10 and r=0.5.

Please helP!

**EDIT:** This is the output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your matrix consists only if integers because when you do basic operations on integers, the results gets rounded automatically.

For example: when you write

```
weights[i][j]=((float)(i/N-j/M)/(1-r));
```

The result of `i/N` is rounded to a integer, `j/M` is also rounded to an integer, and finally, the division by `(1-r)` is also rounded. Your `(float)` cast is a good idea but it's applied **too late**.

You can do several things:

- Cast inside elementary operations, for instance, `float(i)/N` instead of `i/N`
- Use float numbers instead of integers: write `1.0` instead of `1`
- Use floats inside your loops and statements

For example:

```
for(float i = 0; i < N-0.5; i++) {
    for(float j = 0; j < M-0.5; j++) {
        if(i <= floor(N*(1.0-r)/2.0)) {
            // ...
```

It's important you understand that because of **floating point precision**, a test such as `i < N` might or might not pass when `float i = N`. This is why I did a little trick by substracting `0.5` from your loop bounds `N` and `M`.

Comment: In the solution you gave the array indices become floats. So I need a cast there. Which in your opinion is the shortest way (min casts) to solve this?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to **double** your loop variables: you declare `int i; float ii;` then in your loop you increment `for(i = 0; i < N; i++, ii++)` (note the comma). You use `i` for indexes and `ii` for computations and formulas

Comment: yeah, I figured that only finally. Thanks. This problem is solved. But can you help me figure out why the size is 20x10 instead of 10x10?

Comment: @sleeping_dragon As I see on the OpenCV documentation (I'm not an expert), `Mat2F` is a matrix of `Vec2f` objects, which are vectors with **two** values. Maybe this explains why you have twice as many values as you want. Try changing `Mat2f` to `Mat1f`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot. I should have read the documentation carefully. Now only the values are wrong which I think is because of the logic. I ll figure it out. Thanks for all the help.